# Distribute multiple Enterprise Apps

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, enterprise-distribution

I am having Code signing error while distributing second enterprise (when i do Product - Archive)iPhone app. It says

**Code Sign error**: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: XYZ, Inc.' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.

**I have -**

Apple Enterprise License

Created Enterprise Distribution Certificate

Created Separate  App ID for each app

Created Enterprise Provisioning profile for each app

With this my first app works fine. The second app has code sign issue. In Xcode Organizer all profiles are valid and i can select correct provisioning profile from Build Settings but it is throwing above error when i do Product - Archive.

Comment: Did you use the same cert signing request for both your development and debug certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open keychain on your MAC. Look at certificates. If you see multiple instance of 'iPhone Distribution: XYZ, Inc', expand and check if the key is available and the date for the two, delete one of them which is not needed. Lock the changes on keychain. Then retry archiving your app.